# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/SeqLike in Scala project that does not refer to SeqLike class - why?

Tags: scala

I am using Java 12 / Scala 12.3 project https://github.com/dominique-unruh/scala-isabelle/ for the digesting of Isabelle-HOL source code. This is not easy stuff. But project compiles and tests executes correctly.

Then I imported Sext library https://github.com/nikita-volkov/sext/ for pretty-printing Scala object tree (as there is not inner pretty-printing or toJson tree methods in Scala) via addition in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nikita-volkov" % "sext" % "0.2.4"
```

The project compiles but

```
val ctxt = Context("Main")
println(ctxt.treeString)
```

gives error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/SeqLike
    at sext.package$.SextAnyTreeString(package.scala:109)
    at de.unruh.isabelle.Example2theory$.main(Example2theory.scala:151)
    at de.unruh.isabelle.Example2theory.main(Example2theory.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.SeqLike
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 3 more
```

When I check Scala 2.13 documentation https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.5/scala/collection/ then there is no SeqLike indeed, 2.12 has it https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/collection/SeqLike.html

But from where this SeqLike comes in my Scala code that compiles under 2.13? Sext library does not refer to SeqLike as well. How it is possible that such class is required?

Comment: It seems that **sext** library is very very old, unmaintained, not cross-builded and was not properly published neither. I would just look for an alternative, that library will just create troubles with **Scala** versions incompatibility.

Comment: It looks like that library was compiled against an older version of Scala, you may be able to get it to work if you use Scala 2.12 (if not, try 2.11). But longterm, you may need to ask the maintainers to update it to properly cross-compile or find another library.